# How to test private variables in NUNit?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit

I have a a static class which has a private variable.

```
private static Dictionary<strng, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Many public methods of the class access this dictionary object.
Now I want to write NUNit test class (in different library). How can I test this private variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that the question is about NUnit and I don't want to argue whether it's a good or bad practice to test private members. The fact is that it's sometimes necessary, especially when you have to deal with legacy or poorly designed code that you can't refactor.

So I would like to mention that [**Gallio/MbUnit**](http://gallio.org) provides a light API called [**Mirror**](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3amirror) to ease testing with private type members.

---

Example: the following test sample invokes the private method named `SomePrivateMethod` on the `foo` instance.

```
[Test]
public void SampleTest()
{
   var foo = new Foo();
   int actual = Mirror.ForObject(foo)["SomePrivateMethod"].Invoke();
   Assert.AreEqual(123, actual);
}
```

Comment: MSTest offers the same functionality via its Accessor things. But it is still meaningless to unit test, as you should test against the unit, not its inner implementation.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't get into the discussion of weather you should or not test internal methods of an internal class. You can expose your internal methods/properties/classes/etc. to an external library, by using the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute.

For example, if your unit testing library is named *MyUnitTestsLibrary*, just add the following in the AssemblyInfo.cs file of your project (the one being tested).

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyUnitTestsLibrary")]
```

This will make the *MyUnitTestsLibrary* library a friend library of your project to be tested and exposing all of it's internal stuff so you can do unit tests.

Comment: this leads to a world of pain if using signed assemblies.

Comment: @eri0o care to expand?  I'd be interested to hear why this might cause problems down the road

Answer (score 3):

You don't test private variables, you test class' behaviour.

This mean that you should test only the class' public interface.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249847/how-do-you-test-private-methods-with-nunit) question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I find many people supporting both sides of debate on 'If only public interfaces should be tested or private methods as well?' So if at all I need to test private variable, is there any way out?..

Comment: Yes, you can since with reflection - for example - you can bypass C# encapsulation. Maybe Yann's answer could help you out. Anyway, if I was you, I'd look for another way.

Comment: Downvoted: Yann's response is better, this is unhelpful and myopic, assuming the author's view is the only opinion.

Answer (score 2):

When unit testing you should test the public interface, not the private implementation. Check that the interface behaves as expected when you perform operations on it, without checking the Dictionary itself. That way if you decide in future to replace the Dictionary with a different data structure, you won't break all your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I find many people supporting both sides of debate on 'If only public interfaces should be tested or private methods as well?' So if at all I need to test private variable, is there any way out?.

Comment: If you _really_ need to do it, try Yann's method. But the thinking behind it is that the only way your class can interact with the rest of your system is through its public interface, so that's all you need to test. How your class chooses to implement that interface is up to you, _as long as you meet your obligations through the public interface_. Test that thoroughly and tests on your implementation are unnecessary and brittle (will break easily with changes).