# Convert PrivateObject fro MSTest to XUnit

Tags: c#, automated-tests, mstest, xunit.net

I'm migrating MSTest cases to xUnit and couldn't find a way to convert PrivateObject of MSUnit to equivalent in xUnit. Please let me know how to migrate it.

```
private static PrivateObject GetPrivateObject(Object objectToBeWrapped)
{
    return new PrivateObject( objectToBeWrapped );
}
```

Comment: There is no MSUnit, only MSTest

Comment: Don't test private objects expliitly.

Comment: While this isn't xUnit, this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035421/201303